# Mapping Entity Types to a projection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity

I was reading through a tutorial and they said that you shouldn't ever use an entity type to map to a projection. So something like this isnt allowed (where product is an entity created class):

```
from p in db.Products
               where p.ProductID== ProductID
               select new Product { Name = p.Name};
```

So I would create a new class that had something like this:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Then use a query like this:

```
from p in db.Products
            where p.ProductID == ProductID
            select new SomeNewClassName { Name = p.Name });
```

Is this really necessary, or is this just extra work? If I were to create this class it would hold the exact same properties as my Entity Object, so what is the point then? If it is required what is the naming convention that I use with this new class since it is almost identical to my Entity class. Also should I not use the Entity Object to create a strongly type view in a ASP.net MVC Project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What they mean is that you don't want to use an actual entity type as a projection.  You should not, for example, project to an Address entity from a Person entity.

Projection means you are "shaping" the results to be different from their original.  If you are simply returning the original entity, then that's not projection.  You simply do this:

```
from p in db.Products
        where p.ProductID == ProductID
        select p;
```

As for the view, no.  In general, you should not pass entities directly to your views.  There are a number of philosophical and security reasons why you shouldn't, but in most cases just don't.  If you're creating a proof of concept, or it's a trivial internal app, you might be able to get away with it, but any internet facing app should not.

You should create a separate view model, even if it's exactly the same as the entity.  I know it's extra work, but in the long run it pays off, because at some point you will probably want a view model that is different from your entity, then you have to rework things even more.

Comment: great, two follows up though. What would I class this new class then is there a standard naming convention or should it always just be anonymous? Second Then it is ok to use a entity type in a strongly typed MVC view correct if I am not projecting the data?

Comment: @ios85 - It's not anonymous, an anonymous projection is when you simply say `select new { Foo = Bar }` with no type.  The result is an `IQueryable<Product>` in your case.  If you select a single entity, then it's simply `Product`.  See my update about the view.

Comment: Small addition: entity framework does not even accept the former query: _The entity or complex type 'Product' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query_.

Comment: @GertArnold - Correct.  Not only is not advisable to project to an entity, you *can't* project to an entity.

Comment: @MystereMan So interacting with the Database would require I use the entity object, but any interaction with a view would require that I use my new class correct (and subsequently view models if necessary)? Would a cast just be all I need to do then after the interaction with the database? It just seems weird to have to use a class that is exactly the same as another.

Comment: @ios85 - No, I'm not sure you're really getting it.  If you just select the object, then the query returns that entity.  No projection occurs.  If you use the `select new` syntax, then projection occurs, but you cannot project to an already existing entity (one that's in your context) because that's not allowed.

Comment: @ios85 - There are many reasons to not use an entity directly in your view, one of them is for security reasons as any value posted to an action will get mapped to your entity, regardless of whether you intended it or not.  This can lead to security issues when you update your entities (attackers can try an insert things to gain access).  Using a view model forces you to copy only those values you intend to save to the entity, and you only have the items in the view you intend to use (you may not use all items in an entity in a view).  Use AutoMapper to map between View and Data Entity

Comment: @ios85 - Another reason to use view models is that you might have different attributes you need to apply to a view model for validation purposes, that are different from your data model.  For instance, a field may be nullable in your database, but required your view.  If you put required on your data model, it's no longer nullable.  The simple fact is, the requirements of your view, except in very trivial applications, are not going to be the same as your data model.